# Is there a service for User Credit Card -> Eth -> Contract on a chain?

Tags: contract-deployment, contract-invocation

So I have a nice contract infrustructure set up. I have an webserver that interacts with it and provides web pages to my users. I do not want to deal with PayPal\Credit cards myself - I want to have some intermidiary service to get funds from users cards and transfer them (after commission) to my contract payable.

So the logic would look like this:

1. User wants stuff,
2. User clicks Pay,
3. User gets transfered to Card\Payment page of the intermidiary service
4. Intermidiary service calls my contract on the blockchain with my payable method
5. I see the transaction and provide goods to user.

Are there such Intermidiary services already out, are there any with at least 10-100+ user base?

Comment: The main problem for me is that I want to have an app that would be convinient to users with possible no knowledge of any cryptocurrency what so ever, so I need some library\service\bank\... to cover VISA\MasterCard->Eth->Contract call chain.

Comment: Would the call to your blockchain contract involve a transfer of value or are you using the blockchain to track transaction provenance? i.e If I bought a widget for $10,000 (roughly 1ETH) would you expect your an address tied to your contract to receive 1ETH or do you just want to record the fact that $10k was paid?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Money_laundering - nuf said.....

Comment: @Blender its 2022 and I have the exact same requirement, I'd appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2):

There is an issue right now with making such service: when visa/mastercard/paypal/any-other-mature-payment-service finds out someone "sell" crypto currency - they just disconnect such merchant

So if someone declares VISA<->eth gateway - Most likely
it's just a matter of time.

Perhaps in the future this will change

Comment: How can it be that Visa/Mastercard/Paypal just disconnect any merchant "selling" cryptocurrency? Coinbase is such a merchant. Coinbase can charge a Visa or Mastercard credit cards, and put ether in user's account. Of course, it does not satisfy the requirement that a specified contract method be called with the ether. That would need the contract and its method to be registered with the service as a callback. That is not supported, but there is surely a mature payment service that sells cryptocurrency and accepts Visa / Mastercard as payment. It is https://www.coinbase.com

Comment: @AjoyBhatia Yeah, sure) "charge visa or mastercard"
Maybe that's why they work only in particular countries and have long list with conditions for each of them.
Obviously  it's because they use some trick in each country. And again it's just a matter of time when they "suddenly meet technical issues with card processing"

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no such a service.

Actually, there could be many later. But, as of now, there is no service, library or bank that provides what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Check https://limepay.io sounds exactly what you are looking for.